# handling float arguments python

Tags: python, error-handling, floating-point

I have a function that takes an optional argument like so:

`myProgram -n 8`

I want to add in error handling that will exit the program and print an error message if the argument that the user enters is a float.  How would I test for this if the argument always comes in as a string?

Comment: You say function but your example is a program.  Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [str.isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
>>> '12345'.isdigit()
True
>>> '12.345'.isdigit()
False
```

If you want to support negative numbers, strip the sign off first:

```
>>> '+12345'.strip(' -+').isdigit()
True
>>> '-12345'.strip(' -+').isdigit()
True
```

Answer (score 2):

It may seem heavy-weight at first, but the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module can do exactly what you want. The first example on the page shows an integer-only argument (notice the `type=int` part):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                   help='an integer for the accumulator')
```

Calling that example with `python deleteme.py 3.5` (i.e. 3.5 is the argument that should be an integer) gives the following output:

```
usage: scriptname.py [-h] [--sum] N [N ...]
scriptname.py: error: argument N: invalid int value: '3.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

To parse command line arguments, you should be using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html).

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-n", type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Usage:

```
[10:39pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] python blah.py
Namespace(n=None)
[10:39pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] python blah.py -n 4
Namespace(n=4)
[10:39pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] python blah.py -n 4.0
usage: blah.py [-h] [-n N]
blah.py: error: argument -n: invalid int value: '4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps do something like this:

```
from math import modf

if modf(float(args.n))[0] != 0.0:
    # ERROR: Float entered!
```

From the [math.modf](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.modf) docs:

> `math.modf(x)`¶ Return the fractional and integer parts of x. Both
>   results carry the sign of x and are floats.

Or alternatively (*as @dawg mentioned*):

```
"." in args.n  # A possible float

# or

args.n.isdigit()  # Returns False if args.n does not contain all digits only
```